# How to print unicode escape sequence from unicode strings in python(3)?

Tags: python, python-3.x, unicode

For instance if my string contains - 'नमस्ते' how do I print all the unicode escape sequence for the alphabets in the string.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
>>> s = "नमस्ते"
>>> s.encode('utf-8')
b'\xe0\xa4\xa8\xe0\xa4\xae\xe0\xa4\xb8\xe0\xa5\x8d\xe0\xa4\xa4\xe0\xa5\x87'
>>> s.encode('unicode-escape')
b'\\u0928\\u092e\\u0938\\u094d\\u0924\\u0947'
```

Answer (score 9):

If you want the `\u` escapes for each character (what you'd type to redefine the string in pure ASCII Python code), use [the `unicode-escape` codec](https://docs.python.org/3/library/codecs.html#text-encodings):

```
>>> 'नमसत'.encode('unicode-escape')
b'\\u0928\\u092e\\u0938\\u0924'
```

If it needs to end up a `str`, rather than `bytes`, `decode` it back as ASCII (and remove the quoting and doubled backslashes on display by printing it):

```
>>> print('नमसत'.encode('unicode-escape').decode('ascii'))
\u0928\u092e\u0938\u0924
```

Comment: It looks like you lost a few chars there. For the OP's string of `'नमस्ते'` I get `b'\\u0928\\u092e\\u0938\\u094d\\u0924\\u0947'`

Comment: @PM2Ring: Sigh. Stupid terminal didn't support the characters, probably lost it in the copy & paste. I hope the OP gets the idea. :-)

Comment: Thanks for the answer! One more question, is there any way I could map the individual unicode escape sequence to its utf-8 symbol?